# Mongoose, MongoDB/Atlas, Express 404 Not Found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to MongoDB and I've been troubleshooting this issue for a while now and I simply can't figure it out. Every guide I follow results in a 404 and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my file structure:

```
-models
    image-upload.js
-routes
    recogImages.js
server.js
```

image-upload.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const imageUploadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
 },
image: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
 },
uploadDate: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now,
 },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("ImageUpload", imageUploadSchema);
```

recogImages.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const ImageUpload = require("../models/image-upload");

//Getting all records

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
   try {
   const recogImages = ImageUpload.find();
     res.json(recogImages);
   } catch (err) {
     res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
   }
});

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const recogImageRouter = require("./routes/recogImages");

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
// db.on("error", (error) => console.log(error));
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error"));
db.once("open", () => console.log("Connected to Database"));

app.use("./recog-images", recogImageRouter);
app.listen(port, () => console.log("server started on port: " + port));
```

Whether I run MongoDB locally or use Atlas, I get a connection to the database but when I query `GET http://localhost:3000/recog-images/` I get 404 Not Found Cannot GET /recog-images/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
app.use("./recog-images", recogImageRouter);
```

to:

```
app.use("/vbox-recog", recogImageRouter);
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my side, the GET request is http://localhost:3000/recog-images/ so that should be fine. I have tried changing it for the sake of trying, but nothing changes.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I have a fullstop there. What a stupid mistake, thanks for the help.